# Is google fit sync strava activity calories

Tags: android, google-fit, strava

In google fit not properly sync strava activity calories, google fit shows only sync steps and activity name.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the post of Strava support:

> Strava will send activity time, distance, and calories to Google Fit
>   and will receive weight from Google Fit. The option to connect with
>   Google Fit is available on the Strava app's activity save screen, by
>   editing your profile, and under Settings > Link Other Services.

You can check more about the post [here](https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/216919267-Google-Fit-Integration).

Additional reference: [See Google Fit documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/)